# Dictionary entry "Vérselas y deseárselas"

Tags: pronombres

In my dictionary there is an entry belonging to "ver":

**vérselas y deseárselas para conseguir algo**

which should mean something like "take a great effort to obtain sth.". I have seen a similar phrase containing vérselas before in a book and now I have to know. What is this "las" referring to? Is there an implicit omitted word?

Comment: I like this question (+1). I've heard *vérselas negras para ...*, which means having to confront a very difficult situation. I don't know the origin.  So, if the origin of the term you asked about is elucidated, so would be mine.

Comment: Here is another example of 'las' referring to something omitted: 'Te las deseo felices' -- I wish you luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Indeed. Something hidden, could be anything. It is a cliche phrase, itself. 
Nobody knows where it comes from, and we use it not very often because it is a quite old expresion, but it is commonly used in books and it's a nice way to express the difficulty of doing something.

Comment: I did a small research and there is no info available on the net easily to get an explanation of the origins of this expresion. Nobody knows where it comes from , just that.  :-)

Comment: Si quieres ver el uso de verselas molesta a una mujer en cuba...ella diria fulano va verselas conmigo...y mejor fulano que no se aparezca...lol

Comment: Thank you, I'll take this. Also thanks @Emilio Gort for an enlightening example.

Comment: Se pone " fulano va A vérselas conmigo"

Comment: Si @darkgase lo que pasa que lo escribi del cel, seria bueno saber el origen de las palabras fulano y esperanzejo